# Highcharts version 6 dynamic annotations not applied when running getSVG()

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts version 6 gives you the ability to add annotations. The following JSFiddle shows it adding an annotation at the mouse location each time you click on the chart. If you then run get svg (button) it produces an SVG but it does NOT include the dynamically added annotations. If you run SVG with annotations applied at runtime, they apply correctly..

Any ideas?

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {


 chart: {
    events: {
      click: function(e) {
        chart.addAnnotation({
          labels: [{
            point: {
              x: e.chartX,
              y: e.chartY
            },
            text: 'Some info...'
          }]
        });
      }
    }
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }],

  annotations: [{
    labelOptions: {
      backgroundColor: '#000'
    }
  }],

});

// the button handler
$('#button').click(function() {
  var svg = chart.getSVG()

  document.body.innerHTML = svg;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tzsn17cn/

Answer (score 0):

After diggging into this it appears that exporting module does not correctly assign the annotations in the SVG. getSVG() function creates a "sandbox" chart, so copies all the features of that chart into a sandbox chart before creating the SVG.

```
                options.series = [];
                each(chart.series, function(serie) {
                    seriesOptions = merge(serie.userOptions, { // #4912
                        animation: false, // turn off animation
                        enableMouseTracking: false,
                        showCheckbox: false,
                        visible: serie.visible
                    });

                    if (!seriesOptions.isInternal) { // used for the navigator series that has its own option set
                        options.series.push(seriesOptions);
                    }
                });
```

Above is line 1020 in exporting.src.js - you can see that it copies the chart.series into options.series...

It does not do this for annotations, and simply uses the ones created at runtime. To correct this, I've added 3 lines of code at 1035:

```
options.annotations = [];
                each(chart.annotations, function(annon) {
                    options.annotations.push( { labelOptions: annon.options.labelOptions, labels: annon.options.labels } );
                });
```

This copies ALL annotations (inc runtime ones) into options.annotations

I can confirm this correctly creates an SVG and everything is fixed.

**To further update on my answer**

You do not actually need to use the internal getSVG function, but instead produce plain HTML using chart.getChartHTML(), then chart.sanitizeSVG(chartHTML) to produce an exact replica of what you are seeing on the chart.

For example:

```
var chartHTML = chart.getChartHTML();
var svg = chart.sanitizeSVG(chartHTML);
```